# magento 2: session length recommendation

Tags: magento2, session, server-setup

I was asked today to increase the php session length to 86400 (24 hrs) for one of our magento 2 sites.  I am guessing this is to make guest's cart items be persistent for 1 day.  I am used to session length being ~20 minutes so I am unsure of the effects of such an increase.

Are there any security/performance drawbacks to this increase.  If so, are cookies a better alternative for persistence than increasing the php session length?

Answer (score 0):

If that is indeed their aim then there is a better solution. Enable **Shopping Cart Persistence**. You will find it in **Stores > Configuration > Customers > Shopping Cart Persistence**. You can chose the time out there (the default is a year).

Docs are here: http://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/sales/cart-persistent-configuration.html